# Local KD -- can't access physical address 0xFFFFFFF0 but you can with RwEverything

Tags: windbg, address

I've never been able to access 0xf0000000 range using `!db` on local debug, and I've tried `` !db -m 00000000`fffffff0 `` and `` !db [uc] 00000000`fffffff0 ``. I only get `Physical memory read at fffffff0 failed`. It works fine on RwEverything. Any ideas?

Comment: So you have a KD session to a target computer when you do that? For example I get the same with just `-m` but the `[uc]` works perfectly fine for me. Using a kdnet connection to a Windows 10 VM.

Comment: @0xC0000022L I have a WinDbg connection to a VirtualBox VM over a pipe connected to a virtual COM1 port, and I also tested all variations of the commands using `kd -kl` on my local machine, neither work. On my local machine however, RwEverything works fine for this purpose -- but I like to understand why it's not working

Comment: @0xC0000022L That's weird, it worked on remote KD but not remote WinDbg

Comment: But your target does have 4 GiB of "physical" memory, right?

Comment: Yes it has 8GiB, but this range maps to virtual flash so that's irrelevant. It does work on WinDbg, I made a mistake (I did ``!db [uc] 00000000`fffffff0`` which didn't work at that time because I was on bootmgr (so it couldnt read past 4GiB). I tried it again on WinDbg with ``!db [uc] 00000000`ffffff00`` and it worked). This however does not work on `kd -kl` no matter what, which is a shame because I'm more interested in my own hardware -- RwEverything is what I have to use

Comment: I'd recommend writing up your own answer, given you found out what was wrong and why (the boot loader uses real mode, I think ... at least early on).

Comment: kd -kl is not real kernel debugging it works on some sort of dump mechanism and is asnapshot of system as itexistedwhen it was dumped and does not necessarily contain stuff that are irrelevent for a glance of system state

Comment: @blabb I thought that it was only livekd that did that -- once again, it should be able to do this if I could write a driver to do  it myself :/

Comment: winapi NtOpenSection , MapViewofSection or its r0 MmMapIoSpace with \\deviece\PhysiscalMemory  or check ReadPhysical from dbgeng orcheck the whole IDebugDataSpaces methods

Comment: @blabb Yeah but I kinda wanted to know what was going on with local kd. Maybe I'll have to debug local kd itself remotely lol

Comment: you dont have to debug remotely just run .dbgdbg from the child to spawn a parent